# Width 100% for 2 html tables is not working in .xls file

Tags: html, excel, html-table

I'm trying to open a .xls file which will has all html content. 
In the html content, I'm trying to include 2 tables of width 100% (viewport width of the spreadsheet).

If I just include only the 1st table, WIDTH=100% works. But when I include the 2nd table, both the tables width seems to be auto and not as wide as it works with just 1 table.

Following is the contents of the .xls file :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Open in Excel as well as browser (this is ignored by Excel)</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <H2>Useful HTML tags understood by Excel</H2>
    <BLOCKQUOTE>The list given below is not an exhastive list of all tags understood by Excel.
    Where there are several codes that achieve the same effect, I
    have only included one of them.</BLOCKQUOTE>

    <TABLE BORDER=YES WIDTH=100%>
    <TR>
        <TH WIDTH=20%><B>Tag</B></TD>
        <TH WIDTH=30%><B>Valid Attributes</B></TD>
        <TH WIDTH=50%><B>Excel interpretation</B></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>TD</TD>
        <TD>BGCOLOR=colour</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR=YELLOW>Background colour for the cell</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>B</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>-</TD>
        <TD><B>Bold</B></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>TD, TH</TD>
        <TD>ROWFIELD</TD>
        <TD>Pivot table: Type of pivot table</TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <BR/><BR/><BR/>
    <TABLE BORDER=YES WIDTH=100%>
    <TR>
        <TH WIDTH=20%><B>Tag</B></TD>
        <TH WIDTH=30%><B>Valid Attributes</B></TD>
        <TH WIDTH=50%><B>Excel interpretation</B></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>TABLE</TD>
        <TD>ALIGN=LEFT|RIGHT|CENTER|JUSTIFY</TD>
        <TD>Table and its placement</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>TABLE</TD>
        <TD>WIDTH=nn</TD>
        <TD>Size of entire table</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>TABLE</TD>
        <TD>CROSSTABGRAND=NONE|ROW|COLUMN|ROWCOLUMN</TD>
        <TD>Pivot table: where grand totals to be placed</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>TD, TH</TD>
        <TD>ROWFIELD</TD>
        <TD>Pivot table: Type of pivot table</TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

To be clear, my requirement is I need to render 2 html tables, both of width 100%.

Please comment if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Put them them into a main table.

```
<TABLE WIDTH=100%><TR><TD>

    <TABLE.......

</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>

    <TABLE......

</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks for the idea, but I'm trying to fix it without changing the existing html structure which already has 2 separate tables. I'm looking to fix by changing some html properties or some css. Any ideas ?

Comment: I guess when you put several seperate tables, excel consider them as  columns so i dont know how you can do this.